# Using for loop in R to combine column values based on preceeding column conditions

Tags: r, for-loop

I am working with a big dataset with multiple observations for a certain gene, on varying dates and with varying expression levels. [Data used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmNjE.png)

I would like to sum all the 'expression' column values *if*:

1. They belong to the same gene (column 'gene' i = column 'gene' i+1)

AND

2. They are measured on the same date (column 'date' i = column 'date' i+1)

The output should be something like this (each gene should have 1 observation per date, i.e. the sum of all the expression levels of that gene on that date):
[The_desired_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3DeT.png)

I have tried making a for loop, but I am relatively new to R and having troubles with creating a dataframe out of the loop. An alternative solution might be better.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please use `dput` to share your data set instead of using images.

Comment: `library(dplyr); your_data %>% group_by(gene, date) %>% summarise(expression = sum(expression))` ?

Answer (score 0):

How big is "big"? If you really have a large dataset, you are **much** better off with `data.table`.

Here is an example with 10MM rows.

```
#   made up example: YOU should provide this
#
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
df <- data.frame(gene=sample(1:1e6, 1e7, replace=TRUE), 
                 expression=rpois(1e7, 5), 
                 date=sample(43000:44000, 1e7, replace=TRUE))
##
#
library(tictoc)       # for timing functions
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
##
#
tic()
result.1 <- df %>% group_by(gene, date) %>% summarise(expression = sum(expression))
toc()
## 40.83 sec elapsed
##
#
tic()
result.2 <- setDT(df)[, .(expression=sum(expression)), keyby=.(gene, date)]
toc()
## 3.03 sec elapsed
```

So `data.table` is 13 times faster in this example.